# "pair required" error when trying to count how many times the first number is repeated in a list of lists with Scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I am trying to count how many times the first number of the list of list called one, two or three is repeated, the idea of the code that I made is for example to choose the list of list called "one" and then take the first letter that has "a" inside and then compare in this case the first value that would be "10" with the others in this list , in this case I should get it to say that the "10" was repeated once, then it would continue with the other two "b" and "c", but when doing the following code

```
(define a (list 10 2 3 54 6 9 7 10))
(define b (list 5 1 8 6 5 5 4 77 8 6))
(define c (list 80 80 80))
(define e (list 99 156 54 48 99))
(define d (list 16 94 75 30 56 16 8 16))
(define one (list a b c))
(define two (list c e b a))
(define three (list b c d e))

; receives 'one', 'two' or 'three' and finds how many times the first number of the list is repeated in the list of lists
(define (find-repeated-number list)
  (define (find-repeated-number-helper list)
    (if (null? list)
        0
      (if (equal? (car list) (car (cdr list)))
          (+ 1 (find-repeated-number-helper (cdr list)))
          ; displays the number of times the first number of the list is repeated in the list of lists
        (find-repeated-number-helper (cdr list)))))
  (find-repeated-number-helper list))

(find-repeated-number one)
```

I get the following error, why is it? how can i get what i want to do? I would appreciate any help

```
*** ERROR: pair required, but got ()
     While loading "./jdoodle.sc" at line 19
Stack Trace:
_______________________________________
   0 (car (cdr list))
         at "./jdoodle.sc":14
   1 (equal? (car list) (car (cdr list)))
         at "./jdoodle.sc":14
Command exited with non-zero status 70
```

Comment: What is the cdr of a list with a single element?

Comment: Also, you're passing your function a list of lists and compare those lists, but keep talking about numbers...

Comment: the idea of the code that I made is for example to choose the list of the list called "one" and then take the first letter that has "a" inside and compare in this case the first value that would be "10" with the others in this list, In this case, I should get it to say that it was repeated once, then it would continue with the other two "b" and "c", since they are listed as numbers, treat them as numbers, does the error have anything to do with that?

Comment: Put a `(write list)` at the beginning of `find-repeated-number-helper` and see if what it looks like as the function recurses is what you think it is.

Comment: that throws me the error that I mentioned, but when I do the same but placing a list (write one) I get ((10 2 3 54 6 9 7 10) (5 1 8 6 5 5 4 77 8 6) (80 80 80) ) which would be more or less what I want, after that I want to count how many times the "10" is inside the lists, I tried to do that code, I searched a lot, but I don't get the solution

Comment: Is this homework? What Racket languages or functions are you allowed to use?

Comment: It is a problem that they gave us to study, I have been preparing for an exam in which similar problems will possibly come, in principle it should be to use the same language without adding much more, there is no solution on the page so I am stuck on this "recursion" exercise, several others I was able to solve and I use Scheme online in paiza.io

Comment: And what is the expected output for this example? Is it 1 2 2? Are you allowed to use functions like `count`, `filter`, `length` and `for-each`?

Comment: aa yes, those functions if I can use them, the output for the list of lists "one" and "a" is something like "number of times the first number is repeated: '10' is '1' time".  then it would follow the list "b" which is also inside "one", in case of "b" it would be something like this: "number of times the first number is repeated: '5' is '2' times", and finally "one" is left with 'c' where it would be the same but with, '80' and '2' times, each number inside the ' ' would be variables, I have experience with other languages, but this paradigm is different and I draws a lot of attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure if the main point of this exercise is to write low-level recursive code or use some functions provided by the standard library (in this case, `count` or a combination of `filter` and `length`), but here's my wild guess:

```
(define a (list 10 2 3 54 6 9 7 10))
(define b (list 5 1 8 6 5 5 4 77 8 6))
(define c (list 80 80 80))
(define e (list 99 156 54 48 99))
(define d (list 16 94 75 30 56 16 8 16))
(define one (list a b c))
(define two (list c e b a))
(define three (list b c d e))
    
(define (find-count lst element)
    (count (lambda (n) (= n element)) 
                        lst))
                    
(define (print-count lst)
    (let ((number-count (find-count (cdr lst) (car lst))))
        (write (string-append 
                            "number of times the first number is repeated: "
                            (number->string (car lst))
                            " is "
                            (number->string number-count)
                            (if (= number-count 1) 
                                " time"
                                " times")))
        (newline)))
    
(for-each print-count one)
```

Output:

```
"number of times the first number is repeated: 10 is 1 time"
"number of times the first number is repeated: 5 is 2 times"
"number of times the first number is repeated: 80 is 2 times"
```

Comment: thank you very much, when I answered a comment I also thought about whether recursion was really necessary, but with your answer it became clear to me how it could be solved, I have to learn about what you used and commented on, I mark you as the best answer since it serves and helps me, in addition to contributing a lot, now I will investigate more about the answer, thank you very much.